# Changing the basis of a representing matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be the following bases of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ respectively:
$$\left( \left(\begin{array}{c} {2} \\ {-1} \end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{c} {-3} \\ {2} \end{array}\right) \right) \text{and} \left( \left(\begin{array}{c} {2} \\ {-2} \\ {2} \end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{c} {-2} \\ {1} \\ {-1} \end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{c} {-2} \\ {1} \\ {-2} \end{array}\right) \right).$$
The matrix ${}_{\mathcal{B}} [f]_{\mathcal{A}}$ representing the linear mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ with respect to the bases A and B is the following:
$${\left[\begin{array}{cc} 2 & -3 \\ -3 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{array}\right]}$$

Find the matrix which represents the mapping $f$ with respect to the standard bases of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I tried to use the formula for ${}_{\mathcal{B}} [f]_{\mathcal{A}}$ to work out what $f$ does and then use basis vectors to do the transformation but was unsuccessful. I would appreciate guidance on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the matrix product

$\pmatrix{2 & -2 & -2 \cr 2 & 1 & 1 \cr 2 & -1 & -2} \pmatrix{2 & -3 \cr -3 & -2 \cr 2 & 1} \pmatrix{2 & 3 \cr -1 & 2}^{-1}$

First we convert from the standard basis of ${\bf R}^2$ to the given basis of ${\bf R}^2$, apply the transformation, then convert back to the standard basis of ${\bf R}^3$.